# Incorporating Django's system checks into unit test suite?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

I recently deployed some broken code to our staging environment. The new code failed [Django's system checks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/checks/) (error messages reproduced below, though this question is more general). Our unit test suite ran cleanly. My question is this: what is the right way to ensure that system checks get run before code can be deployed?

Initially I guessed that the tests were able to run without performing system checks because we use pytest instead of Django's test runner. However, adding a simple test and invoking `manage.py test` showed that the Django test runner also runs without performing system checks.

One idea I had is to run the `manage.py check` command in our build pipeline, and fail the build on a nonzero return value. A downside of this approach is that it'd introduce another developer step before code could be committed (e.g. remember to run `manage.py check` in addition to running the unit test suite).

Another idea is to add a unit test that runs the system checks. This seems technically feasible, but is it consistent with the purpose and design of Django's system check framework?

I note that [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/checks/#writing-tests) has a section on writing tests for custom checks, which doesn't quite get at what I'm asking. I don't see other documentation on incorporating system checks into tests in the Django docs.

Error messages:

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
myapp.MyCoolModel.linked_groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'MyCoolModel.linked_groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'MyCoolModel.primary_group'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'MyCoolModel.linked_groups' or 'MyCoolModel.primary_group'.
myapp.MyCoolModel.primary_group: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'MyCoolModel.primary_group' clashes with reverse accessor for 'MyCoolModel.linked_groups'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'MyCoolModel.primary_group' or 'MyCoolModel.linked_groups'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25415), not running checks along with the tests was a regression that was introduced in version 1.8, and has recently been fixed.

As described there, an easy solution appears to be to create your own [test runner](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/advanced/#defining-a-test-runner) that inserts a `call_command('check')` at the start of `run_suite()`. See the [actual fix](https://github.com/django/django/pull/6294/files) for an example.